# My Wordpress blog won't load through Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, javascript

My Wordpress blog won't load on my dashboard if I view it on Tor browser (I'm using Firefox through Tor). It says Wordpress can be "partially" viewed only on Tor. What does that mean? Is there a way I can view and make changes on my Wordpress blog through Tor?

Comment: What tells you WordPress can be "partially" viewed? Is it a WordPress.com blog or a self-hosted WordPress installation?

Comment: Facing the same issue here. 1. Can't go to wp-admin page, it takes me back to Reader page.
2. When I click on MySites, it shows all the frames but no data in it. Keeps showing "Loading My Sites" and the sites never show up.
3. When I try to post a blog, it throws an error "An error occurred while loading. User cannot edit posts".
4. I can't save my account settings or profile either, save button is disabled. Everything works good on Firefox without Tor. Any help to get me started on wp would be really helpful.

Comment: Try posting to the mobile site, m.wordpress.com. It is a much simpler site and worked for me when I had the same issue.

Comment: In the NoScript drop-down menu, there is a section for blocked objects. Try temporarily allowing all objects, as well as scripts.

Comment: As a workaround, you can enter the admin panel through the mobile page https://m.wordpress.com.

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable noscript '**allow**' for your dashboard. It may be the **javascript** disabled.

Or as it seems from the question and it is not browser based issue, try different relay / bridges if it is really related to the fact you are using Tor.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this on both a hosted installation, and a wordpress.com site.

The hosted installation works as it should. There's no need to turn off Noscript. Everything under `http://foobar.com/wp-admin/` is accessible.

The wordpress.com blog - `http://foobar.wordpress.com/wp-admin/` - is full of Javascript, so Noscript has to be deactivated. 
However, even after allowing scripts, the site only partially loads. There's nothing - no pop-ups, warnings, etc. - stating that this is expected (so I'm unsure what the OP is referring to).

By "partially loads", it seems to only load the frames of the pages, and doesn't load the actual data/content. (The page I looked at had spinning loading icons where the data should be.)

Looking at the page source for both TBB and FF versions of the same page gives completely different sets of code, I *think* because the TBB version is stuck on a redirect page. I can't tell you why. I haven't found anything else on Google.

Answer (score -1):

In "Privacy and Security Settings", just uncheck "Restrict third party cookies..."
That's the only way to make wordpress.com work with Tor Browser...